# calling one python script from another python script with arguments stored in a string

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to call a Python script from another. I am using the `subprocess`-module and calling it like this:

```
subprocess.call(["python","script.py","parameter_name parameter_value"], shell=False)
```

The thing is when I call it this way it works fine for a single parameter. When I have multiple parameters I tried running it this way

```
subprocess.call(["python","script.py","parameter_one_name parameter_one_value", "parameter_two_name parameter_two_value"], shell=False)
```

This does not work for some reason and the script does not give out any error message as well. So, I tried doing this

```
os.system("python script.py parameter_one_name parameter_one_value parameter_two_name parameter_two_value)
```

This works and the script works as expected. The question I have is is it possible to call the script when the parameters are stored in a string?
For example,

```
parameter = parameter_one_name parameter_one_value+parameter_two_name parameter_two_value)
```

execute script with parameter

I could not find anything so far on SO, so it would be a great help if anyone could help.

Comment: Hey thank you anyone looking at the question. Using 
os.system("python scriptname.py"+' ' +parameter) did the trick! Of course, if there are better ways to do this, please let me know!

Comment: In most cases, it is better to import the module (`import script`) and call various functions in it (`result = script.func(arg1, arg2)`) instead of running it as a script from within another Python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If parameters are in a dictionary `d`:

```
import sys
import subprocess

params = [x for pair in d.items() if all(pair) for x in pair]
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'script.py'] + params)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing each parameter's value as a separate item in the list:

```
subprocess.call(["python","script.py","parameter_one_name","parameter_one_value", "parameter_two_name","parameter_two_value"], shell=False)
```

If needed, you can compose your parameter list from smaller lists:

```
param1 = ["parameter_one_name", "parameter_one_value"]
param2 = ["parameter_two_name", "parameter_two_value"]
subprocess.call(["python","script.py"] + param1 + param2, shell=False)
```

I have no idea how exactly your scenario works when you call it with a single parameter + value in a string; it shouldn't, but without seeing the *actual* values you're passing, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The scenario is that I get the input values from the user through a Tkinter front end. I need to call the script using these values. The values are basically paths to folders. Most of these are optional parameters to the script and depending on what values the user has given in the optional parameter I need to call the script. So, I stored the values in a dictionary as a key value pair and I am calling the script by concatenating the key and value for non null values. Of course, I add only the non null values to the dictionary in the first place. Thanks again!